# Error Handling Issue with Try/Catch in Powershell

Tags: powershell, error-handling, try-catch

I have been working on the following example from one of Don Jones' powershell books as part of my personal development and am having some serious trouble getting the try/catch construct to work as it should.  As you can see, when the `catch` block executes, it sets a variable called `$everything_ok` to `$false` - which should trigger the `else` block in the following code.  Which it does - the logfile is appended as per my expectations.

However it does not stop the script from ALSO executing the code in the `if` block and spewing out 'The RPC Server is unavailable' errors when it tries to query the made-up machine 'NOTONLINE' (Exception type is `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException`).

What makes this even stranger is that I went through the script with breakpoints, checking the contents of the `$everything_ok` variable along the way, and it never contained the wrong value at any point.  So why on earth is the `if` block still executing for 'NOTONLINE' when the condition I have specified ( `if ($everything_ok = $true)` ) has not been met?

Am I doing something wrong here?

```
function get-systeminfo {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
    Retrieves Key Information on 1-10 Computers
    #>
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param (
        [parameter(mandatory=$true,valuefrompipeline=$true,valuefrompipelinebypropertyname=$true,helpmessage="computer name or ip address")]
        [validatecount(1,10)]
        [validatenotnullorempty()]
        [alias('hostname')]
        [string[]]$computername,
        [string]$errorlog = "C:\retry.txt",
        [switch]$logerrors
    )
    BEGIN {
        write-verbose "Error log will be $errorlog"
        }
    PROCESS {

        foreach ($computer in $computername) {
            try {$everything_ok = $true
                gwmi win32_operatingsystem -computername $computer -ea stop
                } catch {
                $everything_ok = $false
                write-verbose "$computer not Contactable"
                } 
            if ($everything_ok = $true) {
                write-verbose "Querying $computer"
                $os = gwmi win32_operatingsystem -computername $computer
                $cs = gwmi win32_computersystem -computername $computer
                $bios = gwmi win32_bios -computername $computer
                $props = @{'ComputerName' = $cs.__SERVER;
                        'OSVersion' = $os.version;
                        'SPVersion' = $os.servicepackmajorversion;
                        'BiosSerial' = $bios.serialnumber;
                        'Manufacturer' = $cs.manufacturer;
                        'Model' = $cs.model}
                write-verbose "WMI Queries Complete"
                $obj = new-object -type psobject -property $props
                write-output $obj
            }
            elseif ($everything_ok = $false) {
                if ($logerrors) {
                        "$computer $_" | out-file $errorlog -append
                        }
                }
        }
    }
    END {}
}

get-systeminfo -host localhost, NOTONLINE -verbose -logerrors
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equals sign in Powershell is used as the assignment operation. `-eq` is used to test for equality. So your if statement is assigning $true to $everything_ok, which then tests true.

Comment: Nice one, thanks!  It turns out in this case I can also leave the assignment operator out altogether, as it's a boolean value.  Knew it would be something simple...